# JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray when requesting json

Tags: android, json

I've sent parameter to my server but in return it sent error message,

```
JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

this is my code:

```
// Creating volley request obj
    JsonObjectRequest taxiReq = new JsonObjectRequest (url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

                    try {
                        JSONArray taxiJsonArray = response.getJSONArray("taxi_list");
                        // Parsing json
                        for (int i = 0; i < taxiJsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject obj = taxiJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            Taxi taxi = new Taxi();
                            taxi.setTaxiname(taxiJsonArray.getString("taxiname"));
                            taxi.setThumbnailUrl(taxiJsonArray.getString("image"));
                            taxi.setdeparture(taxiJsonArray.getString("departure"));
                            taxi.setarrive(taxiJsonArray.getString("arrive"));
                            taxi.setseat(taxiJsonArray.getInt("seat"));
                            taxi.setcost(taxiJsonArray.getInt("cost"));

                            // adding taxi to taxi array
                            taxiList.add(taxi);
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    // notifying list adapter about data changes
                    // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Requesting Taxi Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    })
```

and this is my json:

```
{
  "error": false,
  "taxi_list": [
    {
      "image": "http://localhost/androidapp/taxiprofile/1.jpg",
      "taxiname": "Taxi 1",
      "from": "PTK",
      "to": "SGU",
      "departure": "08:00:00",
      "arrive": "13:00:00",
      "seat": 7,
      "cost": 12
    },
    {
      "image": "http://localhost/androidapp/taxiprofile/default.jpg",
      "taxiname": "Taxi 2",
      "from": "PTK",
      "to": "SGU",
      "departure": "08:00:00",
      "arrive": "13:00:00",
      "seat": 2,
      "cost": 15
    },
    {
      "image": "http://localhost/androidapp/taxiprofile/2.jpg",
      "taxiname": "Taxi Untung Selalu",
      "from": "PTK",
      "to": "SGU",
      "departure": "09:00:00",
      "arrive": "14:00:00",
      "seat": 3,
      "cost": 13
    }
  ]
}
```

I've tried to change JSONObject to JSONArray but it still come with errors...
maybe because I tried to get object but there isn't one...

**EDIT:** new error, after I changed the code

```
error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to int
```

in line:

```
taxi.setTaxiname(obj.getString("taxiname"));
```

any help?

Comment: what does the json look like?

Comment: please check your Json response format..your code is perfect... according to me

Comment: I've update my code, any help...

Answer (score 1):

you have to change your `Volley` request to `JsonObjectRequest`. So your code will be:

```
// Creating volley request obj
        JsonObjectRequest taxiReq = new JsonObjectRequest (url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                        JSONArray taxiJsonArray = response.getJSONArray("taxi_list");
                        // Parsing json
                        for (int i = 0; i < taxiJsonArray .length(); i++) {
                            try {

                                JSONObject obj = taxiJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                Taxi taxi = new Taxi();
                                taxi.setTaxiname(obj.getString("taxiname"));
                                taxi.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("image"));
                                taxi.setdeparture(obj.getString("departure"));
                                taxi.setarrive(obj.getString("arrive"));
                                taxi.setseat(obj.getInt("seat"));
                                taxi.setcost(obj.getInt("cost"));

                                // adding taxi to taxi array
                                taxiList.add(taxi);

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }

                        // notifying list adapter about data changes
                        // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Requesting Taxi Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        })
```

Comment: new errors show up, incompatible types: String cannot be converted to int in line: taxi.setTaxiname(obj.getString("taxiname"));

Answer (score 0):

Your "JSONArray response" is not a JsonArray It is a JsonObject try this once

```
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                        JSONArray responceArray = response.getJSONArray();

                        // Parsing json
                        for (int i = 0; i < responceArray.length(); i++) {

                              ------------- Your code------------
                          }
                      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're expecting for a JSONArray, but your top level element is actually an object:

```
{        <--- This is a JSON Object
  "error": false,
  "taxi_list": [
    {
      "image": "http://localhost/androidapp/taxiprofile/1.jpg",
      "taxiname": "Taxi 1",
      "from": "PTK",
      "to": "SGU",
      "departure": "08:00:00",
      "arrive": "13:00:00",
      "seat": 7,
      "cost": 12
    },
```

You need to change this:

```
JsonArrayRequest taxiReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
        new Response.Listener<JSONArray>()
```

To request a JsonObject instead.

Answer (score 0):

Make StringRequest instead of JSONObjectRequest and use this method it will work fine.

**Problems** in your code:

1. you were taking values directly from array and not from jsonobject.
2. you were not checking for the response came from the server is correctly formatted in JSON or not. StringRequest will help you on that matter.

```html
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String s) {
            Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);

                if (jsonObject.getString("error").equals("false")) {
                    JSONArray taxiJsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("taxi_list");
                    // Parsing json
                    for (int i = 0; i < taxiJsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject obj = taxiJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        Taxi taxi = new Taxi();
                        taxi.setTaxiname(obj.getString("taxiname"));
                        taxi.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("image"));
                        taxi.setdeparture(obj.getString("departure"));
                        taxi.setarrive(obj.getString("arrive"));
                        taxi.setseat(obj.getInt("seat"));
                        taxi.setcost(obj.getInt("cost"));

                        // adding taxi to taxi array
                        taxiList.add(taxi);
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // notifying list adapter about data changes
            // so that it renders the list view with updated data
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Requesting Taxi Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```